# SQLite UPDATE command not updating database

Tags: python, sqlite, sql-update

I'm very new to SQLite, python, and programming generally and am attempting to create a home media server database. I'm trying to write a program that will add new entries to a database I've created and allow me to edit existing entries as well. While I am able to add entries just fine, updating specific entries is another matter. As an example, I'd like to be able to update a specific movie title to a new one without me knowing what id it has before hand. The section of code in my program that is causing problems is this one:

```
def editMedia():
    while True:
        print('Catagories: title, genre, type, director, length, rating')
        editValue = input('What would like to edit?: ')
        if editValue not in ('title', 'Title', 'genre', 'Genre', 'type',
                        'Type', 'director', 'Director', 'length', 'Length',
                        'rating', 'Rating'):
            print('Invalid entry: Please choose one of the catagories')
            continue
        elif editValue in ('title', 'Title'):
            while True:
                oldTitle = input('Enter old title: ')
                if len(oldTitle) < 1:
                    print('Invalid entry: Old title must have a value.')
                    continue
                else:
                    while True:
                        updateTitle = input('Enter new title: ')
                        if len(updateTitle) < 1:
                            print('Invalid entry: New title must have a value.')
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                break
                cur.execute('''UPDATE Movie SET title = ? WHERE title = ?''', (updateTitle, oldTitle))
        print("Record Updated successfully ")
        break

    conn.commit()
```

The code I used to create the tables that I'm editing is:

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('mediadb.sqlite')
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.executescript('''
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Director;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Genre;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Type;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Movie;

CREATE TABLE Director (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE Genre (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name   TEXT UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE Type (
    id INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    name    TEXT UNIQUE);

CREATE TABLE Movie (
    id  INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT UNIQUE,
    title TEXT  UNIQUE,
    genre_id  INTEGER,
    type_id INTEGER,
    director_id INTEGER,
    minutes INTEGER, rating INTEGER);
''')

conn.commit()
cur.close()
```

When I try to update a specific movie title the program runs without error, but when I use DB Browser for SQLite to inspect my database in order to confirm that the title was updated, I find that nothing was changed.

What am I doing wrong here? Is what I'm after even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I've just run this up on my Laptop, and can see you've got a few issues. There are also many improvements possible, but I'm sure that'll come with time as your skills improve

I've rushed some basic changes, but this works and I'll explain my findings below

```
def editMedia():
    while True:
        print('Catagories: title, genre, type, director, length, rating')
        editValue = input('What would like to edit?: ').lower()
        if editValue not in ('title', 'genre', 'type', 'director', 'length', 'rating'):
            print('Invalid entry: Please choose one of the catagories')
            continue
        elif editValue == 'title':
            while True:
                oldTitle = input('Enter old title: ')
                if len(oldTitle) < 1:
                    print('Invalid entry: Old title must have a value.')
                    continue
                else:
                    while True:
                        updateTitle = input('Enter new title: ')
                        if len(updateTitle) < 1:
                            print('Invalid entry: New title must have a value.')
                            continue
                        else:
                            break
                conn = sqlite3.connect('mediadb.sqlite')
                cur = conn.cursor()
                cur.execute('''UPDATE Movie SET title = ? WHERE title = ?''', (updateTitle, oldTitle))
                cur.close()
                conn.commit()
                print("Record Updated successfully ")
                break
        break
```

- Calling **lower()** on the users input of what they're trying to edit means that you don't have to worry about CAPS
- You were calling **break** *before* your update command, so the script was never getting there
- Even after fixing that, you were trying to execute a command on a closed cursor which gives a ***ProgrammingError***; I'm opening it for you again, then running the update command, then closing and committing

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've got it working now and it is such a good feeling watching it all do what I intended it to.

Comment: @holycow - You're welcome mate! Welcome to the life of a Developer; the proudest moments are seeing our creations come to life. If my answer helped, kindly mark it as accepted to close the loop on the question